# Can't see my Pi on the connected devices on my phone anymore

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I'm a complete beginner concerning the Raspberry Pi. I have an Pi 3 model B and I was working on an RFID project. Everything was working fine until I wanted to power off my Pi with `sudo halt` to do some hardware configurations; (which I do every time I want to power it off).

When I reconnected my Pi to my PC through the USB cable I couldn't see my Pi on the connected devices on my phone anymore, and I don't know how to access the Raspbian terminal without putting the IP address of my Pi into Putty and accessing it with SSH.

What happened? And what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why did you connect USB to PC - both are master devices, and you would need a non-standard cable? There is too little information to answer whatever your question is.

Comment: Are you running an access point on the RasPi?

Answer (score 0):

Under assumption that your Pi's WiFi/Access Point is not working

You can try following options,
1. Power with 2A adapter instead of powering from PC.
2. If you have a network Router, connect via Ethernet cable and check for the IP address.
3. Connect your Pi to PC monitor or LCD to analyze the problem.